# select2 select2-removed event find tag position

Tags: tags, jquery-select2

I have a select2 multiple tag control (limited to 2 in my case) where the positions of the tags are important.

I am listing on the select2-removed event, and want to find the position of the tag being removed.

I am able to break on the remove event, and inspect e, but this give me the id of the element, not the position in the tag field.

```
$('#mytags').on('select2-removed', function(e){

     console.log('removed', e)

});
```

How can I determine which tag (first or second) was removed?

Answer (score 2):

By the time the `select2-removed` event fires, the item has already been removed, so you can't check against the value of the Select2 control at that time. You could, however, check when the `select2-removing` event fires. Then if you want the position of the removed item at the time of the `select2-removed` event, you could store it in a `data` value on the select element.

```
$('#mytags').on('select2-removing', function(e) {
    var $select = $(this);
    $select.data('select2-removedIndex',  $select.select2('val').indexOf(e.val));
}).on('select2-removed', function(e) {
    alert($(this).data('select2-removedIndex'));
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvcq3unn/)

Comment: @crafter - Are you still working on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27098199/859640)?